# сжатие изображений

Tags: php

Дня доброго Вам. Нашел код на просторах интернета. Соединил его воедино с загрузкой картинок на сервер, но не устраивает скорость, с которой выполняется данная функция. Чем больше вес файла, тем дольше выполняется функция. Оно вроде и понятно, но может можно как то оптимизировать ? Или подскажите аналог. Спасибо.

```
public static function resize_photo($filesize,$type,$tmp_name)
{
    $size = 648576; 
    if($filesize>$size){
        switch($type){
            case 'image/jpeg': $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name); break; 
            case 'image/png': $source = imagecreatefrompng($tmp_name); break; 
            default: return false;
        }
        imagejpeg($source, $tmp_name, 80); 
        imagedestroy($source);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Думаю можно, но проще изменить сервер, использовать кэширования для сжатия в реалтайм.

Comment: @Node_pro как бы Вы оптимизировали пример кода из вышеприведенного примера ? Может "подчерпну" для себя что то новое )
Сервер..хм, тоже можно, но хотелось бы с кодом для самообразования

Comment: Ну тут вопрос не в оптимизации кода, который вряд ли будет быстрее, ввиду того, что вся работа выполняется внутри библиотечных функций. А скорее в организации процесса. Например не делать ресайз во время загрузки. Cложные манипуляции с файлом производить уже в фоне. У меня в одной системе например картинки грузятся, в БД отмечается что файл есть и что уменьшенной копии нет. В очередь RabbitMQ пишется сообщение. Другой процесс, получив сообщение ресайзит картинку, пишет в БД статус. При запросе клиентом картинки отдается маленькая, если еще не готова - то большая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте mozjpeg, не скажу будет ли она быстрей против imagejpeg функции(которую я не использовал никогда) но точно уверяю вас что mozjpeg одна из лучших библиотек в сравнении скорости сжатия и качества или используйтесь простейшим вариантом апнув сервер.

Comment: Спасибо большое )